# plone.app.multilingual language change URL

Tags: localization, plone, multilingual, linguaplone

The LinguaPlone had `/switchLanguage` script that allowed contruction or "other language" URLs by knowing the one of the languages and the target language to redirect to. It did cost extra request to Plone, but worked.

Is there an alternative for plone.app.multilingual?